# Как получить время простоя программы?

Tags: c#

А именно время простоя в котором не было переключения на окно программы.

При этом может происходит работа в других программах.

Comment: Думаю нужно проверять наличие фокуса в приложении подробнее [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162834/determine-if-current-application-is-activated-has-focus)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот вам небольшой пример на WPF:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // счётчик времени

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Activated += (o, args) => sw.Start();
        Deactivated += (o, args) => sw.Stop();
        if (IsActive)
            sw.Start();

        // ну и отображение
        StartIdleTimeUpdating();
    }

    async void StartIdleTimeUpdating()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(250);
            Target.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="250" Width="250">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Run Text="Idle time: "/><Run Name="Target"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]